# Super slow clone from Github

Tags: git

I have an estimated downstream between 350 megabit/s and 400 megabit/s - and yet, cloning the Servo project is taking forever:

```
$ git clone servo/servo
Klone nach 'servo' ...
remote: Enumerating objects: 128, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (128/128), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (112/112), done.
Empfange Objekte:  28% (165829/573378), 190.95 MiB | 14.00 KiB/s
```

(Sorry for the german there!)

This is not the only repo that is facing this. Now, I am on MacOS and I do have the firewall enabled but I couldn't find any hint about it being the bottleneck. Plus, I am connected via gigabit ethernet directly to my router, which is also gigabit enabled - meaning I should be getting the whole, entire bandwidth. And yet I only keep getting 14KiB/s?

What are the best optimizations I can do to my Git config in order to speed up cloning? I already installed `git-lfs`, but it does not seem to do anything (or do I have to configure it somewhere?).

**EDIT**
I just tested against a Linux box I have, and it is using the entire possible downstream to clone that very same repo. So it has to be an issue on my system... Any ideas?

Comment: Does your *repo* use git-lfs?  From what I can tell (given that it's 28% through a download and it's already downloaded almost 200MB), it isn't.

Comment: I was conceived by an article that read "Git LFS - Clone faster". The repo does not actually use LFS as far as I know.

Comment: There are configuration steps you need to follow to take advantage of Git LFS.  Just installing it client-side isn't enough.  If the repo isn't aware that it's there it's not going to leverage it.

Comment: This is most likely a networking issue, rather than Git itself. What, precisely, I have no idea, but a tcp-level tracing tool might show something.

Comment: @torek Can you recommend me one? I had the same guess, so I just tested to download via WiFi - and that one alone seems to improve things a lot. But I'd rather use a wired connection instead.

Comment: Well, I'm old-school and would use the tcpdump on the Mac, but I don't know if I should say that I'd *recommend* it. :-)

Comment: Is it only with git that you're getting this issue, or other applications as well?

Comment: What is CPU/memory usage? Looks like you have huge objects, maybe it's not in fact network issue but git cannot index the received pack. What are your git versions on both systems?